# Yii2. Запись даты и времени в БД, ActiveForm

Tags: yii2

Возникла необходимость записать в таблицу БД определенные время и дату (время и дата в таблице отдельные поля), через ActiveForm. Не хочу загромождать проект 100500 плагинами, есть какие-нибудь другие варианты, штатные Yii?

Comment: Ну смотри. Ты можешь сделать просто присвоение после вызова модели. $model = new Model() $model->date = '2018-03-13' $model->time = '13:00:00' $model->save()

Comment: Уже ближе. НО, хочу через ActiveForm->field. Почему вот после данной конструкции <?= $form->field($model, 'date')->input('text'); ?> не записывается корректная дата в БД, а записываются нули типа: 0000-00-00. В поле же Input я дату ввожу в таком формате 2018-09-12 например.

Comment: ps: Ну Вы поняли, в таблице БД есть поле date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем нашел я решение, и как всегда всё банально просто. Добавил в правилах модели вот такой код:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['title', 'content', 'date', 'time'], 'required'],
        **['date', 'date', 'format' => 'php:Y-m-d'], // для даты** 
        **['time', 'time', 'format' => 'php:H:m:s'], // и для времени**
        [['author_id'], 'integer'],
        ['title', 'string', 'length' => [5,25] ],
        [['content'], 'string', 'length' => [5,255] ]
    ];
}
```

Итого из формы все приходит как надо, дата и время в БД записывается корректно и в контроллере->actionCreate ничего не надо исполнять. Вот сама форма:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => 25]) ?>    
   <?= $form->field($model, 'content')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>  
   <?= $form->field($model, 'date')->input('text'); ?>
   <?= $form->field($model, 'time')->input('text'); ?>
   <div class="form-group">
       <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('backend', 'Create') : Yii::t('backend', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
   </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

И в контроллере стандартно:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Event();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    .....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Доброй ночи. Для записи даты в базу есть поведение yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior
Используется следующим образом

```
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;

public function behaviors()
{
  return [
    TimestampBehavior::class,
  ];
}
```

Подробней [здесь](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html)

Так же есть встроенный yii\jui\DatePicker.

Остальное зависит от того, что Вам надо в конечном счёте.

Comment: TimestampBehavior automatically fills the specified attributes with the current timestamp.

Мне не текущее время и даты нужны, а любое, скажем 2018-06-12

Comment: А DatePicker что-то он у меня не встроенный

Comment: Значит в последних версиях исключили. Отдельно надо поставить. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-jui-datepicker.html

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui